# Publishing to ArcGIS Server using ArcPy and AnalyzeForSD()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server

I'm trying to publish some data layers to ArcGIS Server, using ArcPy.  This is my first time trying this.

I can create my feature classes, and save them in a file geodatabase.  I can then create layers corresponding to them.  I then save the layers to individual layer files, and thence to an mxd.

I then create an SD draft document (using CreateMapSDDraft).  No problems so far.

The next step seems to be calling AnalyzeForSD, passing in the SD draft.

Two things at this point.  One is that that is supposed to, as near as I can tell, return a Dictionary with 'errors', 'warnings', and 'messages'.  However, I was having some issues and was getting an IOError that had a Dictionary just like that attached to it.

Was I doing something wrong there (other than the problems that were causing the IOError)?

Second, once I fixed those problems, I started getting another IOError, but the explanation for this one was:

> Unidentified error

Comment: It's really difficult to troubleshoot this sort of issue with all the logs available and knowing how Server has been configured. Without this information in the Question, you'd probably be a lot better off opening a case with Tech Support.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this error is occurring before contacting the server.  Certainly, AnalyzeForSD doesn't take connection information as one of its arguments